# CSS Styling on Elements Items

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have some list items and I want the corresponding drop down menu to align to the left, for some elements, and some should remain. (See [link](http://www.atlastechng.com/demo/telime/).) When you hover over the "more", "opinion", and "lifestyle" link, it aligns to the right and out of the page causing lengthy stuff. I want just those 3 menu lists to align to the left when you hover, while the others not mentioned to remain. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: If you post some code or a JFiddle that would help a lot

Comment: Please explain better by the word some code.
Or is there a way whereby i can align some ul list items(li) to the left and some to the right on mouse hover

Comment: Please take a look at the site http://www.atlastechng.com/demo/new/tellme/ and hover through the opinion and lifestyle menu link..i want those two alone to float to the left while others to the right..can u help ??

Comment: The website isn't loading

Comment: Hello Adam, the website is loading
Please i need to get this done asap
I just need an idea of how to format some list (li) elements to the right While some floats to the left
please help a newbie grow !

Comment: hey now I can see it. I suggest you make a new class that is the same except it includes 'position:inherit; float:right;' and apply that to the nav elements. I'm goign to look into this

Comment: @OlasunkanmiAdeniji Note: the link in your post is different than the link you have in your comments.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through your html I suggest you look for the classes *leaf* *first leaf* and *last leaf* and add another class in your CSS that mimics these except *float:right*. then apply this to the menus you want to float right.

If this makes the elements go to far to the right maybe try

```
position:inherit;
left:-Xpx;
```

And replace X with the amount of pixels you want it to go left.

On [this site](http://www.atlastechng.com/demo/new/tellme/)

Luck

Comment: Thanks Adams, God bless you real good, i will try it and get back to you...pls send me ur email address to dolpaz02@yahoo.com..i have somefin for you if it works.
Thanks

Comment: Have you managed to fix it? I checked it a couple of days ago and it looked the same. I must say the code looked very overcomplicated

Comment: Hello Adam, I have been away for some months..trying to pursue my M.sc degree..the job have been given to another fellow while i was away. its now totally off me, thanks so much !